# Django: how to override core handlers

Tags: python, django, inheritance, handler, middleware

I have made a custom middleware and if it throws exception, it is automatically  handled by `BaseHandler` function `get_response` (django.core.handlers.base). My exception `ObjectDoesNotExist`, by default, is not handled and therefore a function `handle_uncaught_exception` takes care of it. But it considers all error as 500 Internal Server (even if it is a 400 Bad request) and returns default django error html template with 500 code. Here is my code:

custom_middleware.py:

```
class CustomMiddleware(object):
"""
custom middleware
"""
def process_request(self, request):
    try:
        # if agent doesn't exists then return json response
        agent = Agent.objects.get(agent_token=agent_token)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
        raise Exception(exception_code=400, detail=e, response_msg="You are not an authorized agent", request= request_data)
```

This automatically is handled by BaseHandler.get_response()

So to solve the problem what I did was inherited the BaseHandler and override get_response function adding exception handler for my error and which gives a **json response** rather than HTML template.

base.py

```
from django.core.handlers.base import BaseHandler

class ExceptionHandler(BaseHandler):

    def get_response(self, request):
        my code
```

But this doesn't help as it calls the base class method even after overriding.

Here is the traceback:

```
  File "/webapp/apps/middleware/custom_middleware.py" in process_request
  49.  agent = Agent.objects.get(agent_token=agent_token)

File "lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  122.  return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  387.  self.model._meta.object_name

During handling of the above exception (Agent matching query does not exist.), another exception occurred:

File "lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  123.  response = middleware_method(request)

File "webapp/apps/middleware/request_log.py" in process_request
  54.   raise Exception(exception_code=400, detail=e, response_msg="You are not an authorized agent", request= request_data)
```

Any help

Comment: This is quite hard to follow, unfortunately. Are you saying that even though your middleware catches ObjectDoesNotExist, the error still falls through to the default exception handler middleware? Also please show the error traceback that that produces.

Comment: Yes, as soon as an exception occurs in middleware, the handler listens to it and gives the 500 html template, which is then passed to process_response middleware. whereas process_exception is not affected and does nothing. I have found a solution by parsing html response from handler in process_response and returning a JSON response. But that is not at all a good solution.

Comment: Sorry, but that's impossible. If your code is catching the exception, it can't ever be passed up to the base handler. I think you will need to show some real code - and, as I asked, the exception traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have added code in the middleware above and also added the traceback. As I said, base.py is returning error as html template which I parse in process_response and process_exception has no part to play in this. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you are raising an exception in your except block.

Comment: that's just for logging purpose, but even if I return a simple JSON response, the code goes to base.py, but yes this solves the problem. Thanks. Anyways, can I really overwrite the core handler functions?